# SetInterval does not run from HTML form's onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, setinterval

I just wrote a timer function that does count down from 5 seconds on the page. Next I wanted to create a form that would call the timer function when submitted.

But even though the onClick triggers the function (and console logs "hi"), it never executes setInterval.

Is there a reason why setInterval works when I call the function immediately, but not when I submit the form? After some research, I still can't work out the reason for this.

```
  <body>
    <h1 id="title">
      This a simple timer
      <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="duration" />
        <input type="submit" onclick="timer()" />
      </form>
    </h1>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
```

javascript

```
const title = document.getElementById("title");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

const timer = () => {
  console.log("hi");
  let interval = 5;
  let countdown = window.setInterval(() => {
    title.innerText = "00:" + interval;
    interval--;
    if (interval === 0) {
      title.innerText = "DONE";
      clearInterval(countdown);
    }
  }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No there aren't any errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since HTML forms with action attribute set to empty string submit their form to the current page, you are reloading your page every time you submit since why your JS function never gets called

what you can do is prevent default(reload) behavior by calling `e.preventDefault()` before your `console.log("hi");` statement.

and your `<input type="submit"...` would change to `<input type="submit" onclick="timer(event)" />`

also don't forget to add the parameter to `const timer = e => {...`

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why it didn't occur to me to prevent auto-submission. This solution worked perfectly

Comment: one thing I forgot to follow up about-- why does the function no longer console.log("hi")?

Comment: It should be logging. Can you show us your updated code?

Answer (score 1):

Submitting a form in html means that the URL specified with `action` will be loaded with the data from you form. If you set `action` to an empty string, the current page is reloaded with the form's data. So in your case you are reloading your page everytime you click the submit button.

If you just want to start the timer with a button, you don't need a form and you don't need an input of type submit. Use

```
<body>
    <h1 id="title">
      This a simple timer
    </h1>
    <input type="text" name="duration" />
    <input type="button" onclick="timer()" value="click me!" />
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Also, you shouldn't put anything in your `<h1>` apart from the actual text of your title.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems here. Your html structure. You should try this instead. I added “event” so I could target the input element. But you could also give the form tag a name or set an I’d to target it directly when the submit button gets clicked.

```
 <body>
<h1 id="title"> This a simple timer </h1>
<form action="">
    <input type="text" name="duration" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="timer(event)"/>
  </form>
<script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Previously when the onclick event triggers you update the DOM by replacing the text contents in #title and that tag wraps the form also. I think you should make them independent. And 2, the page gets reloaded so you should handle the page submission by using preventDefault(); on the form. see example below

```
const title = document.getElementById("title");
        const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

    const timer = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log("hi");
        let interval = 5;
        let countdown = window.setInterval(() => {
            title.innerText = "00:" + interval;
            interval--;
            if (interval === 0) {
            title.innerText = "DONE";
            clearInterval(countdown);
            }
        }, 1000);
    };
```

Here is another approach, i adjusted the html and javascript.

> No onclick event

```
<h1 id="title"> This a simple timer </h1>
  <form action="" name="simple_timer">
    <input type="text" name="duration" />
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
```

We just set a form name.

> Javascript set to listen for any submission by that form then prevents it from occuring.

```
const title = document.getElementById("title");
        const timer = document.forms['simple_timer'];

        timer.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log("hi");
            let interval = 5;
            let countdown = window.setInterval(() => {
                title.innerText = "00:" + interval;
                interval--;
                if (interval === 0) {
                title.innerText = "DONE";
                clearInterval(countdown);
                }
            }, 1000);
        });
```

Guess that’s all.

Comment: Why did you suggest using timer(this) instead of timer(event)? It gave me this error-- VM1374 index.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: event.parentNode.preventDefault is not a function

Comment: It's been resolved. i wanted to get the <input type="submit"> element with "this" and prevent the form from being submitted. @henokg did a good job solving this. I've ran a test on a computer and fixed the typeError. All good now.